# how to split the strings into first name and last name

Tags: python, string, split

The namelist is:

```
[J. A. Rubiño-Martín, R. Rebolo, M. Aguiar, R. Génova-Santos, F. Gómez-Reñasco, J. M. Herreros, R.J. Hoyland, C. López-Caraballo, A. E. Pelaez Santos, V. Sanchez de la Rosa]
```

and I need to split it into

```
[[J. A.], [Rubiño-Martín], [R.], [Rebolo], [M.], [Aguiar], [R.], [Génova-Santos], [F.], [Gómez-Reñasco], [J. M.], [Herreros], [R.J.], [Hoyland], [C.], [López-Caraballo], [A. E.], [Pelaez Santos], [V.], [Sanchez de la Rosa]
```

using python regex

Comment: You need quotes around strings.

Comment: Parsing names is not possible with a regular expression, they don't follow consistent enough patterns.

Comment: @Barmar but in this case it does have a pattern: letter(s) followed by a period and the rest of the characters up to the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given input, this regex works. The first group will match any number of tokens followed by a dot, multiple times in greedy fashion. The second group matches everything after the last dot followed by one ore more spaces.

```
^(.+\.)+\s+(.+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/Jxy3Un/1

Here is a [visualization](https://regex-vis.com/?r=%5E%28.%2B%5C.%29%2B%5Cs%2B%28.%2B%29%24):

[image: regex visualization]

But as pointed out in the comments, it could easily break if you get names that don't follow this rather strict pattern.

Comment: Throwing in something more "specific" just for fun :) 
`((\w\.\s?)+)\s+([\w\- ]+),?`
[regex validation](https://regex101.com/r/U1bdfs/1)
This should work if its a raw string or testing full names from a list.
group 1 and 3 will be the interesting ones

*Note: 3rd group might need to include more characters, but this covered the sample input, and assumes no trailing spaces on the surname*

Comment: What if I want to further split the compound surnames. For example: carlos-temm to ['carlos', 'temm'] and santos de la creme to ['santos', 'creme']?

Comment: @Casey, you should open a new question next time. You could use something like this `^([\w\s\.]+\.)+?\s+(\w+)?[-\s](\w+)?$`

Comment: Thank you @TheFoolTh. I did but it got flagged closed because it 'lacked' focus.